# How to push static value at each index of array to create 2d array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working in php where I need to add a static value at each index of existing single dimensional array so that after adding it will become multidimensional array.

Existing single dimensional array:

```
[checklists] => Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 35
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 21
    [6] => 22
    [7] => 27
    [8] => 25
)
```

Static value to be inserted `90`

After insertion array will look like this:

```
[checklists] => Array
(
    [0] => Array(90,20)
    [1] => Array(90,50)
    [2] => Array(90,35)
    [3] => Array(90,23)
    [4] => Array(90,24)
    [5] => Array(90,21)
    [6] => Array(90,22)
    [7] => Array(90,27)
    [8] => Array(90,25)
)
```

I want to know is there any **php builtin function** through which i can achieve this or should i use loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_map, $static is your 90, $array is your array.

```
$array['checklists'] = array_map(function($v) use($static){
  return [$static, $v];
}, $array['checklists']);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/3ugLR

Answer (score 3):

Here we are using `array_map` to achieve the desired output.

**Solution 1:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/804936)

```
$staticValue=90;
$array["checklists"]=  array_map(function($value) use ($staticValue){
    return array($staticValue,$value);
}, $array["checklists"]);
print_r($array);
```

**Solution 2:** `try this simplest one`

```
$staticValue=90;
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    $value=array($staticValue,$value);
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: hey congrats man your are going to cross 10k reputations within a small time period, really amazing (y) party :-)

Answer (score 1):

To modify an array, [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) can be used:

```
array_walk($array['checklists'], 'addStatic');

function addStatic(&$v) {
    $v = [90, $v];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

More easy way you can do this.

```
$array = array();

$array['checklist'][] = array(90, 20);
$array['checklist'][] = array(90, 50);
```